# Android VPN (PIA) and Location Settings

Tags: vpn, geolocation

I am currently using a Private Internet Access (PIA) vpn on my S7 Edge.

If I leave the location/GPS function on while surfing the web "anonymously", will having the location feature on make my VPN useless by providing my location?

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @DavidPostill - I appreciate the additional information. I'll make sure I check out the sources and reading material before posting in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I also use PIA for Android. Through my experience and also from my knowledge of networks, yes, the location of your phone is still your actual location. The only difference using the VPN would have is that the location would be associated with whichever external IP address that has been assigned to your session by PIA.

The only way to hide your location would be to turn it off or spoof your location through developer options. There is currently no option in the PIA for Android app to hid location.